# How to make sudo use root password for some commands and user password for others

Tags: sudo

I know in `/etc/sudoers`, one can put *Defaults rootpw*, but then `sudo` asks for the root password for all commands. Is there any way I can have `sudo` ask for the root password for some commands and the user password for others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defaults can be set for everything or for certain Hosts, Users or Commands

man sudoers says :

> Defaults
>          Certain configuration options may be changed from their default values at
>          runtime via one or more Default_Entry lines.  These may affect all users on
>          any host, all users on a specific host, a specific user, a specific command,
>          or commands being run as a specific user.  Note that per-command entries may
>          not include command line arguments.  If you need to specify arguments, define
>          a Cmnd_Alias and reference that instead.

```
    Default_Type ::= 'Defaults' |
                     'Defaults' '@' Host_List |
                     'Defaults' ':' User_List |
                     'Defaults' '!' Cmnd_List |
                     'Defaults' '>' Runas_List
```

So try :

```
Defaults!cmdlist rootpw
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn turn off root password for specific commands and specific users by adding this line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
username1 hostname1 =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/command_name1,/usr/bin/command_name2
username2 hostname2 =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/command_name1,/usr/bin/command_name2
```